# Facebook Like Box only works in one browser

Tags: facebook, syntax-error, facebook-likebox

I have been trying to get a like box on a website that works for more than one browser (chrome) and I can't seem to make it work.  I've tried FireFox, Safari, IE and nothing.  I could get the default Like Box example to work no problem, but when I use the following code nothing:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=114521595255240&width=292&height=300&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=true&border_color&header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:300px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I also tried:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Forlaborersapprenticeship&amp;width=292&amp;height=427&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I tried with http:  and  https:.  I tried with & inplace of `&amp;`any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
<div class="fb-like-box" 
data-href="https://www.facebook.com/yourfacebookpage" 
data-width="462" 
data-height="400" 
data-show-faces="false" 
data-colorscheme="dark" 
data-stream="true" 
data-border-color="#333333" 
data-header="false"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is live and has content. If there are no active posts, browsers won't have any content to pull and so won't show the like box. Also, try coding the `&` to the full html code of `&amp;`, that helped me.